# eslint - per file parserOptions.sourceType?

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

My project uses Webpack and es6 modules for most of the files. These files run in browser, and bundled by Webpack.

There are just a small number of files, that run in node. They are not touched by Webpack and I don't see any benefit including them in webpack. They don't support `import` as it's not implemented yet in node (or V8).

Now in `.eslintrc`, if I set `parserOptions.sourceType` to `script`, it errs out in the browser files ("`import` and `export` only allowed in module!"). If `parserOptions.sourceType` set to `module`, it errs out in node files.

So how to do per-file `parserOptions`? `/* eslint-env xxx */` doesn't work in this case

### Edit

I can probably use directory-specific `.eslintrc`, but that would mean duplicate all other configs for the sake of changing just one option. Any better option?

Comment: Are you able to take advantage of the the hierarchical nature of `.eslintrc` files? I was under the impression that they inherited the config from any `.eslintrc` in the parent directory. I have a vague memory of using that feature.

Comment: @cartant Ah, thanks! It is hierarchical. It's not mentioned in doc AFAIK. Would you make it a answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to take advantage of the hierarchical nature of [ESLint configuration (`.eslintrc`) files](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files):

> ESLint will automatically look for them in the directory of the file to be linted, and in successive parent directories all the way up to the root directory of the filesystem. This option is useful when you want different configurations for different parts of a project or when you want others to be able to use ESLint directly without needing to remember to pass in the configuration file.

Note that `.eslintrc` files in child directories inherit the configurations from `.eslintrc` files in parent directories, so it's easy to override particular settings.

Answer (score 20):

Another option is using `overrides` as such :

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "overrides": [{
    "files": ["path/to/some/file.js", "path/to/some/folder/**.js"],
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    }
  }]
}
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration

The benefits of such a solution :

- if you need only a single file in a folder to have specific overrides, you can
- if you need to share the same overrides in multiple places, you prevent yourself from having duplicate files (which is good DRY practice).